# CSS, 3d Perspective - Background image peeking into foreground

Tags: html, css, background

I am experimenting with parallax backgrounds, and I have run into an issue. Depending on some circumstances, the background ends up peeking through in front of the fixed block element.

It seems to be dependent on the viewport size, and how far down the user has scrolled. The taller the viewport, and the farther down scrolled, the more apparent the issue.

Normal: [image: normal]
Issue: [image: issue]

---

Code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ow1f6gcj/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.header {
  height: 256px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #222;
}

.header-image {
  height: 256px;
  background-image: url('https://placehold.it/600x400');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: translateY(-50vh)/* Top of screen */
  translateY(128px)/* Middle of header */
  translateZ(-1px)/* Back */
  ;
}

.block {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 256px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
</div>
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-image"></div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: The browser doesn't seem too happy with the last 4 CSS lines for both html and body. When you apply them to body only, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you owe me for this one because I made it my mission to get to the bottom of it. Spent more time than I care to admit.

Remove `translateY(-50vh)` on header-image and add `perspective-origin: top;` to html, body.

Here is the correct code.

```
.header-image {
    height: 256px;
    background-image: url(https://placehold.it/600x400);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: perspective(1px);
    transform: translateY(128px) translateZ(-1px);
}
```

and

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    perspective-origin: top;
}
```

Without `perspective-origin: top;` the `translateZ(-1px)` was moving the content outside the div where the webpage believed the content to be. So keeping the content in place when translating in backwards and removing the offset fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Your z-index is causing the red color to be placed in front of your image.
Remove `z-index: 10000;` from `.block`.

Comment: I want the red color in front of the image. The red color should block the entire website. If you scroll down or make the viewport larger, you can see what I mean